# Cognos LAE Backup Automation (Batch File?)

Tags: batch-file, backup, cognos

Within Cognos 7.4 security.. one would create an LAE file to export all their users...

directions here... http://www.cognos-install.co.uk/articles/backups/access_manager_export_to_lae.asp

Now you'll notice at the bottom "Finally, it is possible to build an automated process for this task, however this is outside of the scope of this document.  If you feel that an automated process is something that is important to your organization then this can be achieved using Technical Consultants with Cognos Planning expertise."

Does anyone have a batch script... or command line for Access Manager.. for exporting an LAE file?   I would like to have automated backups of my users incase of a disaster.   This cannot be the first request for this.

TIA,
   Kirby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub Main()
        Dim objAuthApp As Object
        Dim objAuthDoc As Object
        Dim objLAEConfig As Object
        Dim objDSConfig As Object
        Dim laef

```
    laef = "\\backupsserver\backups\LAEBackup-" & Year(Now) & "-" & Month(Now) & "-" & Day(Now) & ".lae"
    objAuthApp = CreateObject("Authenticator2.Application")
    objLAEConfig = objAuthApp.LAEConfigurations.Add(laef)
    objDSConfig = objAuthApp.DSConfigurations.Add("servername", 389, "o=cognos,dc=com", 0)


    objDSConfig.DefaultSecuritySource = True
    objAuthApp.Export("Default", "Administrator", "password", True, False)
    objAuthApp.Quit()


    objDSConfig = Nothing
    objLAEConfig = Nothing
    objAuthDoc = Nothing
    objAuthApp = Nothing
End Sub
```